# SQL Is it possible to merge multiple results into one int result?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to get the results from this SQL line as one result (All results added together) instead of all results in separate rows?

```
SELECT pr as Totalprice
FROM productdatabase
WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM bdatabase WHERE kid = 2);
```

Comment: `All results added together` you mean `SUM()` or `Combined` ? needs some clarity on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `SUM()` :

```
SELECT sum(pr) as Totalprice
FROM productdatabase
WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM bdatabase
              WHERE kid = 2);
```